# (iOS) OpenGL ES (2.0) Application, how to move the object in Z?

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, depth-buffer

I'm playing with OpenGL ES (2.0) Application (iOS) source code in XCode and was trying to make the colorful square move in the Z coordinate, so I tried to change the shader code from

gl_Position.y += sin(translate) / 2.0;

to

gl_Position.z += sin(translate) / 2.0; 
with no success.

The square doesn't move at all.
It moves well in X and Y thought...
Is there some option I need to activate when initializing OpenGL? Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
I've uploaded an example. This is roughly the OpenGL ES template that XCode generates, I just added the calls to create the depth buffer, and the gl_Position.x to gl_Position.z += sin(translate) / 2.0f in the Shader.vsh.

I wish to see the square move in a sinusoidal form on the Z coordinate but it just won't. Either it keeps still or, if I multiply the sin(), it will appear and disappear in a cycle.

If anyone can help me out I'll be most grateful, since sincerely I do not know what else to do, and believe me I tried alot...

The source is in a zip at: http://cl.ly/24240x2D1t2A3I0c1l1P

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you are looking at has no depth buffer and a perspective matrix intended for 2D GL. Look at the aurioTouch example instead. in the EAGLView class you will notice an option to implement the depth buffer. The two combined (since aurioTouch doesn't implement shaders) should give a better understanding

I think the order of operations you have in your method are causing the problem.
Here's the code I use in my app "Live Effects Cam" which places the live camera as a GL Texture on shapes:

```
#define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(__ANGLE__) ((__ANGLE__) / 180.0 * M_PI)



@interface GLView : UIView
    {
@private
    /* The pixel dimensions of the backbuffer */
    GLint backingWidth;
    GLint backingHeight;

    EAGLContext *context;

    /* OpenGL names for the renderbuffer and framebuffers used to render to this view */
    GLuint viewRenderbuffer;
    GLuint viewFramebuffer;
    GLuint depthRenderbuffer;

    /* OpenGL name for the sprite texture */
    GLuint spriteTexture;
    }

@property (readonly) GLint backingWidth;
@property (readonly) GLint backingHeight;
@property (readonly) EAGLContext *context;


- (void) drawView;
- (BOOL) createFramebuffer;
- (void) destroyFramebuffer;
+ (UIImage *) snapshot:(GLView *)eaglview;

@end




@implementation GLView


@synthesize backingWidth;
@synthesize backingHeight;
@synthesize context;


+ (Class) layerClass
    {
    return [CAEAGLLayer class];
    }



- (id)init
    {
    self = [[super init] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 480.0, 640.0)];     // size of the camera image being captures

    if ( self==nil )
        return self;


    // Set Content Scaling
    //
    if ( HIRESDEVICE )
        {
        self.contentScaleFactor = (CGFloat)2.0;
        }

    // Get our backing layer
    //
    CAEAGLLayer *eaglLayer = (CAEAGLLayer*) self.layer;

    // Configure it so that it is opaque, does not retain the contents of the backbuffer when displayed, and uses RGBA8888 color.
    //
    eaglLayer.opaque = YES;

    eaglLayer.drawableProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                        [NSNumber numberWithBool:FALSE], kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking,
                                        kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8, kEAGLDrawablePropertyColorFormat,
                                        nil];

    // Create our EAGLContext, and if successful make it current and create our framebuffer.
    //
    context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES1];

    if(!context || ![EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context] || ![self createFramebuffer])
        {
        [self release];
        return nil;
        }

    // Final View Settings
    //
    [self setOpaque:YES];
    self.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];

    glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, viewFramebuffer);
    glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    GLfloat zNear = 1.0;
    GLfloat zFar = 1000.0;
    GLfloat fieldOfView = 90;       // Lens Angle of View
    GLfloat size = zNear * tanf(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(fieldOfView) / 2.0);
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake( (CGFloat)0.0, (CGFloat)0.0, backingWidth, backingHeight);

    glFrustumf(-size, size, -size / (rect.size.width / rect.size.height), size / (rect.size.width / rect.size.height), zNear, zFar);

    glViewport(0, 0, backingWidth, backingHeight);

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
    glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);
    glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);  
    glHint(GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST);  
    glHint(GL_POINT_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST);  
    glDisable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);

    // Turn Translucent Textures: OFF
    //
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);

//  // Turn Translucent Textures: ON
//  //
//  glEnable(GL_BLEND);
//  glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    return self;
    }



- (void) drawView
    {
    [context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES];
    }




- (BOOL)createFramebuffer
    {
    // Generate IDs for a framebuffer object and a color renderbuffer
    //
    glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &viewFramebuffer);
    glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &viewRenderbuffer);

    glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, viewFramebuffer);
    glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);

    // This call associates the storage for the current render buffer with the EAGLDrawable (our CAEAGLLayer)
    // allowing us to draw into a buffer that will later be rendered to screen whereever the layer is (which corresponds with our view).
    //
    [context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES fromDrawable:(CAEAGLLayer*)self.layer];

    glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);

    glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH_OES, &backingWidth);
    glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT_OES, &backingHeight);

    // If this app uses a depth buffer, we'll create and attach one via another renderbuffer.
    //
    if ( YES )
        {
        glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &depthRenderbuffer);
        glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, depthRenderbuffer);
        glRenderbufferStorageOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES, backingWidth, backingHeight);
        glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, depthRenderbuffer);
        }   

    if(glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES)
        {
        NSLog(@"failed to make complete framebuffer object %x", glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES));
        return NO;
        }

    return YES;
    }


- (void) destroyFramebuffer
    {
    glDeleteFramebuffersOES(1, &viewFramebuffer);
    viewFramebuffer = 0;

    glDeleteRenderbuffersOES(1, &viewRenderbuffer);
    viewRenderbuffer = 0;

    if(depthRenderbuffer)
        {
        glDeleteRenderbuffersOES(1, &depthRenderbuffer);
        depthRenderbuffer = 0;
        }
    }




+ (UIImage *) snapshot:(GLView *)eaglview
    {
    NSInteger x = 0;
    NSInteger y = 0;
    NSInteger width = [eaglview backingWidth];
    NSInteger height = [eaglview backingHeight];
    NSInteger dataLength = width * height * 4;

// Need to do this to get it to flush before taking the snapshit
//
    NSUInteger i;
    for ( i=0; i<100; i++ )
        {
        glFlush();
        CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, (float)1.0/(float)60.0, FALSE);
        }

    GLubyte *data = (GLubyte*)malloc(dataLength * sizeof(GLubyte));

    // Read pixel data from the framebuffer
    //
    glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);
    glReadPixels(x, y, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

    // Create a CGImage with the pixel data
    // If your OpenGL ES content is opaque, use kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast to ignore the alpha channel
    // otherwise, use kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast
    //
    CGDataProviderRef ref = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, data, dataLength, NULL);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGImageRef iref = CGImageCreate(width, height, 8, 32, width * 4, colorspace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast, ref, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

    // OpenGL ES measures data in PIXELS
    // Create a graphics context with the target size measured in POINTS
    //
    NSInteger widthInPoints;
    NSInteger heightInPoints;

    if (NULL != UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions)
        {
        // On iOS 4 and later, use UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions to take the scale into consideration
        // Set the scale parameter to your OpenGL ES view's contentScaleFactor
        // so that you get a high-resolution snapshot when its value is greater than 1.0
        //
        CGFloat scale = eaglview.contentScaleFactor;
        widthInPoints = width / scale;
        heightInPoints = height / scale;
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(widthInPoints, heightInPoints), NO, scale);
        }
    else
        {
        // On iOS prior to 4, fall back to use UIGraphicsBeginImageContext
        //
        widthInPoints = width;
        heightInPoints = height;
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(widthInPoints, heightInPoints));
        }

    CGContextRef cgcontext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // UIKit coordinate system is upside down to GL/Quartz coordinate system
    // Flip the CGImage by rendering it to the flipped bitmap context
    // The size of the destination area is measured in POINTS
    //
    CGContextSetBlendMode(cgcontext, kCGBlendModeCopy);
    CGContextDrawImage(cgcontext, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, widthInPoints, heightInPoints), iref);

    // Retrieve the UIImage from the current context
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();   // autoreleased image

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // Clean up
    free(data);
    CFRelease(ref);
    CFRelease(colorspace);
    CGImageRelease(iref);

    return image;
    }


@end
```

Comment: As an extension to this: you almost certainly want to stick with ES 1.x for now. That retains the classic OpenGL matrix stack, allowing you to perform this sort of thing quite easily. For ES 2.x, because every stage is now very open ended, you have to deal with the 3d maths for yourself to a much larger extent.

Comment: @up - and what's wrong with that? More code, yes, but more control too. Programming 3D graphics in a low-level API like OpenGL should mean "a lot of 3D maths" in the era of programmable pipelines... I strongly advise against learning old technologies when you can learns the modern ones.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Create default framebuffer object.
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &defaultFramebuffer);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, defaultFramebuffer);

    // Create color render buffer and allocate backing store.
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depthRenderbuffer); <----
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &colorRenderbuffer);

    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderbuffer); <----
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorRenderbuffer);

    [context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:(CAEAGLLayer *)self.layer];

    glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH, &framebufferWidth);
    glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT, &framebufferHeight);

    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, framebufferWidth, framebufferHeight); <----

    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorRenderbuffer);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderbuffer); <----
```

I've added that to my code (the ... <----) and now I get a pinkish screen (lol). Any ideas? This is really frustrating. Shouldn't I do something in the setFrame.. presentFrame..?

Comment: I've added the code I use in one of my apps, "Live Effects Cam" to present the camera as a GL Texture on different shapes

Comment: No success, it seems the depth buffer is being created, but when I move the object in Z it just blinks from time to time. The code is here: http://pastebin.ca/2002989 - to move the object I use the gl_Position.z in the shader... But it just blinks from time to time.. *frustation*